# Why was the plane flown through close proximity to the runway rather than landing there?

Tags: plot-explanation, scorpion

In the series *Scorpion*, they were trying to download a copy of the software from what's left behind on a plane, and from what I understood, the reason they were doing this was that without this software, they wouldn't be able to land the plane because the control tower was offline and they wouldn't be able to guide the planes. However, the climax scene depicts a scene where Walter drives a Ferrari at >200 mph below the plane that's 8 or 10 feet above the ground on a runway while Paige connects a LAN cable from the plane to the laptop.

Why couldn't they land the plane instead? They had clear visibility of the runway, were 8 feet above the ground, and from what's seen on the scenes, there weren't any other planes on the runway either. What has prevented them from landing there at that moment and taxying it to the respective dock or bay?

<sub>I asked this question in scifi.stackexchange.com [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263765/in-scorpion-s1-e1-why-was-the-plane-flown-through-close-proximity-to-the-runway) because I thought it was science fiction, but I was suggested to ask it here instead.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure (and Scorpion has let my streaming platforms), but weren't they in a "local" (ie small) airport instead of LAX "big" airport, so the landing runaway wasn't fit for a "company" plane? If I remember, they had difficulties going to the Airport (traffic), so they chose the diner, and then, chose a local airport.

Comment: Ah, so it is the length of the runway preventing the plane from landing there. I didn't quite catch that information. If you'd like to give is as an answer, I'll be happy to accept. Thanks.

Comment: I'd prefer to rewatch the episode, but I can't (since the tv show has left my streaming platforms). If someone can watch it again and post an answer (and confirm, or find another answer), it's fine by me. It could be the length, the "hardness" of the piste (since it might not be suited for heavy planes, etc.)

Comment: The scene in question is on YouTube (in the US at least). It was written to be cool, and definitely not written to be realistic. So applying real-world reasoning to it will only get you so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a comment that the runways at Klemmer Airfield are too short to land a commercial airliner.

> I still think it's the wrong play; the runways are too short there.

In addition, they aren't dealing with a single aircraft, they're trying to save 56 planes with barely minutes to do it in. Landing *this* aircraft would probably take too long since it would have to stop and the they would have to get on board to complete the software download.